# How to find multiplier x if x * c1 = c2, but x * c1 causes overflow

Tags: c++, hash, stdhash

I am writing a code that will find collisions for `std::hash<std::string>` and trying to reverse some of hash calculation steps.

There is such a multiplication in `std::hash` implementation.

```cpp
size_t hash2 = shift_mix(hash1) * mul;
```

I know `hash2` - from previous step, also I know `mul` - it's constant value = `0xc6a4a7935bd1e995UL`.

`shift_mix(hash1) * mul` causes overflow (`hash2 / mul = 0`), so it takes only last 64 bits of multiplication result.

So, I need a way to find many variants of `shift_mix(hash1)` which satisfy equality. What is the best way to do it? Probably somehow use `__int128_t`?

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication by an odd number modulo a power of two is invertible, so you can "undo" it perfectly, without multiple options appearing. However, division does not work after wrapping, you need to multiply by the multiplicative inverse of `mul` mod 2<sup>64</sup>, which is 0x5f7a0ea7e59b19bd in this case. `0x5f7a0ea7e59b19bd * 0xc6a4a7935bd1e995 = 1`.

```
uint64_t mul_inv = 0x5f7a0ea7e59b19bd;
uint64_t hash1 = unshift_mix(hash2 * mul_inv);
```